# Determining the maximum common value form a single row in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
-----+--------+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------
r_id |  r_user| module | q_1 | q_2 | q_3 | q_4 | q_5 | q_6 | q_7 | q_8 |  q_9
-----+--------+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------
 1   |  test  | 1      | g   | r   | r   | y   | g   | g   | y   | r   |  g
-----+--------+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------
 2   |  test-2| 1      | r   | r   | g   | r   | r   | y   | y   | r   |  g
```

Is there any way to determine the maximum common value for each row? For example, the  first row should result "g" and the second row should result "r".

I can't figure it out how to do that in MYSQL. Any help on that?

Comment: Do you mean the most *frequent* value?

Comment: What if two letters are equally frequent?

Comment: Make a loop and make an array suck as array('test'=>array('g'=>4,'r'=>,'y'=>2),'test-2'=>....); What have you tried? Something tells me that you should have a table with questions and an intermediate one, and other values for the answer...

Comment: @Sébastien: Yes, I meant the most frequent value.

Comment: OK, see my answer below and tell me if you understand the general idea. You have several options open.

Comment: @Passerby: goods comment! But I have coded the php in such a way that they wont be same in number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are working with fixed values or "r", "g" and "y" values. If so, this should work for you.  The inner "PQ" (pre-Query) is getting each row other data elements and then summing each column with 1 IF it's value is the "r", "g" or "y" respectively into 3 count columns.

From that, I'm then using the "Greatest" function which returns the highest value from a given list provided.  If you have all 3 with 3 of same color, they will all be flagged as highest... or even if a 4/4/1 split, two will show as high count.

I didn't know your table name so I just called it "freq1"

```
select
      PQ.r_id,
      PQ.r_user,
      PQ.module,
      PQ.gCnt,
      PQ.rCnt,
      PQ.yCnt,
      if( PQ.gCnt = greatest( PQ.gCnt, PQ.rCnt, PQ.yCnt ), 'yes', '   ' ) as HighG,
      if( PQ.rCnt = greatest( PQ.gCnt, PQ.rCnt, PQ.yCnt ), 'yes', '   ' ) as HighR,
      if( PQ.yCnt = greatest( PQ.gCnt, PQ.rCnt, PQ.yCnt ), 'yes', '   ' ) as HighY,
      greatest( PQ.gCnt, PQ.rCnt, PQ.yCnt ) as HighCnt
   from
( select 
      r_id, r_user, module,
        if( q_1 = 'g', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_2 = 'g', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_3 = 'g', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_4 = 'g', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_5 = 'g', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_6 = 'g', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_7 = 'g', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_8 = 'g', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_9 = 'g', 1, 0 ) as gCnt,
        if( q_1 = 'r', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_2 = 'r', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_3 = 'r', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_4 = 'r', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_5 = 'r', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_6 = 'r', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_7 = 'r', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_8 = 'r', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_9 = 'r', 1, 0 ) as rCnt,
        if( q_1 = 'y', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_2 = 'y', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_3 = 'y', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_4 = 'y', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_5 = 'y', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_6 = 'y', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_7 = 'y', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_8 = 'y', 1, 0 )
      + if( q_9 = 'y', 1, 0 ) as yCnt
   from freq1 ) PQ
```

results created

```
r_id   r_user  module  gCnt   rCnt   yCnt   HighG   HighR   HighY   HighCnt
1      test    1       4      3      2      yes                     4
2      test-2  1       2      5      2              yes             5
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do what you want in MySQL without resorting to many queries and perhaps temporary tables. You could of course much more easily use a single query and do the sorting in PHP with arrays.

Anyway the very organization of your table is wrong for that kind of purpose. You should have a related table where you store all the answers (or whatever `q_1` to `q_9` is). That way you can add any number of questions/answers without having to create columns in your main table.

Then MySQL would be the perfect tool to extract the result you want: you would be comparing rows instead of columns.